# Export MS Access query into Excel

Tags: microsoft-access

In Access, I know that there is a "Analyze it with Microsoft Office Excel" option, but i am creating a database and the person requesting this wants a command button on a form to do the same thing that the "Analyze it with Microsoft Office Excel" button does. So my question is can anyone help me write vba code to export a MS Access query into Excel, formatted the exact way the "Analyze it with Microsoft Office Excel" does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked on the Northwinds db:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acTable, "Customers", "MicrosoftExcelBiff8(*.xls)", "", False, "", 0
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa141534(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Had to change False to true to open Excel, but it worked

Answer (score 0):

If you want a lot more flexibility as to exactly what is being exported where to Excel then see

- [Modules: Sample Excel Automation](http://www.mvps.org/access/modules/mdl0006.htm) - cell by cell which is slow
- [Modules: Transferring Records to Excel with Automation](http://www.mvps.org/access/modules/mdl0035.htm)

I've used such code as a starting point to, for example, include some heading and footer lines, starting the export below the above lines, remove columns from the spreadsheet which were placed there from the query, create multiple worksheets, etc, etc.

However if you want just something basic then Chris gave you the answer.